# Corrupted Content Error with Firefox 7.0.1

Tags: java, firefox, inputstream

When I am trying to download something through my website using Firefox 7.0.1, I got following Error:

> Corrupted Content Error
>
> The page you are trying to view cannot be shown because an error in the data transmission was detected. Please contact the website owners to inform them of this problem.

I use Java Input Stream to download content from my website.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: How do you use a Java InputStream with Mozilla (Firefox?) ?

Comment: I use Java Input Stream for download my code.....
and whenever I testing the code in Mozilla it gives me error....

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what it has to do with Java Input Stream but Firefox shows this error if the headers sent by the webpage are invalid. For example: multiple `Location` headers, multiple `Content-Disposition` headers. See also: [bug 681140](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=681140) (note that it is in the Tech Evangelism component - this is about fixing the websites, not the browser). Note that the reason for this behavior is security: such headers often indicate an [HTTP Response Splitting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_response_splitting) vulnerability being abused.